# Associate a list of files to a list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, file-upload

I'm trying to create a calendar where each element links to a number of files in a list.

For example: the Calendar contains meetings, each meeting should have its agenda and its meeting minutes as PDF files. I can't use simple file attachements because each file has to have columns like "Type" "Due date"...

Do you have an idea?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: In a nutshell, I want to display a list in another list and when I add an element to the containing list I want to add, in the same form, elements to the contained list.

Comment: How about having a document set or a folder with agenda and MOM which will look up your meeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the files in a document library then create a lookup column in the calendar list to lookup the files from the libraries.

About Lookup Column:
[Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Comment: I created a meetings list and a attachements library, both lists are related to each other so you can lookup which meeting is attached to which attachement and vice versa. Now how can I automatically add the lookups in one list when I manually add one in the other. Example: I add an attachement in the attachement library and a meeting in its lookup column, now I want that in the meetings list the attachement is added automatically as a lookup to the meeting;